# does gcp signed url work with google pub/sub?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-authentication

In my application design, there are many clients who push events to a google pub/sub topic. It is not good to have service account for each client. Therefore, I was looking for a way where clients can push events to pub/sub without having service account. I found signed url. But looks like it is built only for cloud storage.
How can I achieve the same signed url feature to push event to pub/sub?

Comment: Most Google Cloud Services use OAuth. Pub/Sub does not support Signed URLs. Signed URLs are designed to be used by web browsers to access static assets. The format of Signed URLs is HTTP centric (HTTP Method, Content-Type, etc.).

Comment: @JohnHanley May I request to post this as an answer for better visibility. I also looked into it but did not see any recorded articles about this in Google's public documentation.

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley for clarification. Any alternative of signed url ? basically I want to avoid creating n number of service account .

Comment: For machine-to-machine authorization, using a service account is the correct option. Your question does not have details such as where the code runs. For Google compute services, you can use the attached service account.

Comment: so clients are gitlab CI jobs which send CI specific data to pub/sub. gitlab is also hosted in gcp. gitlab CI jobs run in different gcp project.

Comment: Use Google Workflow Identity Federation with Gitlab.

Comment: @JohnHanley This looks a good option. However my gitlab is hosted on GCP itself. federation is useful when workload exists on on-prem or other clouds (aws,azure etc).

Comment: That detail should be in your question. However, I have answered your question in my answer. For Pub/Sub you must use Google OAuth access tokens. Untrusted/insecure clients should not be directly accessing Pub/Sub. Your backend server should authenticate clients and receive requests on their behalf. Your backend then interacts with Pub/Sub.

Answer (score 1):

Most Google Cloud Services use OAuth for authorization. Pub/Sub does not support Signed URLs.

Signed URLs are designed to be used by web browsers to access objects stored in Cloud Storage. The format of Signed URLs is HTTP centric (HTTP Method, Content-Type, etc.).